# App still rotates in landscape mode when device's Screen Orientation setting is off

Tags: android, android-screen-support, android-screen

I set my app to rotate 180 degrees by setting android:screenOrientation="sensorLandscape" on the activities in my manifest. But when the setting for screen orientation in device is turned off, the app is still rotating.

My app needs to rotate 180 degress in landscape mode but should not rotate when screen orientation setting is turned off. How can I solve this?

Comment: what is your api level?

Comment: android:minSdkVersion="9" android:targetSdkVersion="17"

Comment: Seems duplicate issue [similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45983438/app-auto-rotates-even-with-device-orientation-locked)

Answer (score 2):

I believe you should be using `landscape` and not `sensorLandscape`. The `sensor` type attributes don't respect the orientation lock, and will still rotate regardless of that setting.

I couldn't seem to find out for sure whether `landscape` meant both 90 and 270 degree landscape, but give it a shot -- I believe that's your answer.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation regarding the sensor landscape. Earlier I tried landscape, and does not rotate, which is why I changed to sensor landscape. http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html

Answer (score 1):

I Haven't used this personally but from the doc [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#screen) I can see

> **Note**: When you declare one of the landscape or portrait values, it is
>   considered a hard requirement for the orientation in which the
>   activity runs. As such, the value you declare enables filtering by
>   services such as Google Play so your application is available only to
>   devices that support the orientation required by your activities. For
>   example, if you declare either "landscape", "reverseLandscape", or
>   "sensorLandscape", then your application will be available only to
>   devices that support landscape orientation. However, you should also
>   explicitly declare that your application requires either portrait or
>   landscape orientation with the  element. For example,
>   . This
>   is purely a filtering behavior provided by Google Play (and other
>   services that support it) and the platform itself does not control
>   whether your app can be installed when a device supports only certain
>   orientations.

so you can try

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.screen.landscape"/>.
```

Comment: and thanks for the answer. I added it to help in Google Play filtering.