# App auto rotates even with device orientation locked

Tags: android, orientation

I am working on normal activity based application.
I have turned off device orientation from device settings.
When I run my app on device, the app changes orientation based on device movement.
I have no clue how can an app rotate even when device orientation is locked.
There is no such instance/issue reported or ever asked on stack overflow or any other forum.
Please point out, what I might be missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was very silly mistake, but I thought of sharing here in case any one else faces this issue.
At a point, in my application, I was setting device orientation programmatically to SCREEN_ORIENTATION_FULL_SENSOR:

```
activityContext.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_FULL_SENSOR);
```

This allows app to change orientation, based on sensor, even when user has locked the device orientation.

Answer (score 1):

You could check if device rotation is off or on and then lock it, like this:

```
if (android.provider.Settings.System.getInt(getContentResolver(), Settings.System.ACCELEROMETER_ROTATION, 0) == 1){
    //Auto Rotate is on, so don't lock

    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR);
}
else{
    //Auto Rotate is off, so lock

    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
}
```

Comment: I don't want my activity to be locked. I want them to be able to change orientation, only when device orientation is not locked in device settings.

Comment: Why do i need to lock in first place? If device orientation is locked, my app should not rotate. It's simple.

Comment: What if user again turns on screen rotation from device settings. Above solution won't be able to switch orientation in that case.

Comment: No but your app overrides the device rotation if you don't deal with it

Comment: You could check this if-statement every ten seconds or so using a timer